# Unable to sync PGP keys seahorse

Tags: gnupg, seahorse, keyserver

Ok so I tried for the first time to use PGP keys for email encryption in Evolution. I followed some instructions online, created a key, but coz I encountered some problems I decided to delete the key and restart the proces. (This fact is probably irrelevant, because I got similar errors when doing it.)

Now I have no key and I go to Remote: Sync and publish keys. Firstly it says that there are 6 keys selected for synchronisation. Why? I do have some passwords saved in here, will it sync those too??

And last, when I click sync I first get two errors:

> Couldn't retrieve keys from server: pool.sks-keyservers.net
>
> Couldn't communicate with server 'pool.sks-keyservers.net': Internal Server Error

and

> Couldn't retrieve keys from server: keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371
>
> Couldn't communicate with server 'keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371': Internal Server Error

Than the progress stops and no progress is made, it just says:

> Synchronising keys... Exporting data

Any help?

Comment: Can you post the `keyservers` available in seahorse  , through the same sync option menu.

Comment: hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371, 

    hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net and 

    ldap://keyserver.pgp.com
these are the keyservers i have by default.

Comment: They are right , have you tried revoking them. do you have any firewall like UFW installed and enabled.

Comment: Because I wanted to start over(and some error in evolution about public key), I deleted all keys in preferences. Regarding the firewall- I have a pretty much clean install and have not messed with firewall preferences, but I think it is on by default in ubuntu?

Comment: Then not a firewall issue. have you integrated pgp to evolution mail.

Comment: Evolution is not a problem, I added a key, however when tried to send an encrypted mail I got an error saying that this is not a public key. So I deleted it and started over.

Comment: It's 2020 and I also run into this problem, but there does not seem to be a solution. Is there anyone that can help out here?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by:

1. Remove all existing keyservers from the Sync box (by default `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371`, `hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net`, and `ldap://keyserver.pgp.com`).
2. Add them over again (keeping the same settings).
3. Press Sync.

Don't know why this works, but it does.

Comment: Hey" I tried removing and adding back keyservers, but the problem still persists.

Comment: I am using Xubuntu 18.04 and there hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371 is added by default. I wonder why?

Comment: Does not work for me unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to go directly to https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/ and submit the ASCII-armored version of your key.

You can generate it like this:

```
gpg --armor --export $your.email.address@foo.com
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the following approaches worked for me, I'm not sure if the first will fix it but I will certainly encourage for the 2 approach.

This anwer was inspired by both @Pranesh-Prakash and @ConorSheehan1 answers.

1. Using Password & Keys GUI app, go to Preferences, and activate the checkbox for **Automatically synchronize modified keys with key servers**. Retry sync

If the synchronization fails then try this:

2. Using Password & Keys GUI application, go to Preferences.

   - In the **Keyservers** section, add a new one using the `Add keyserver` button

     - Select *HTTPS* as the `Key Server Type`.
     - Add **keyserver.ubuntu.com** (no protocol, no port) as `HOST`
   - (My current version of *Password*&*Keys* doesn't update automatically to reflect the changes so I have to close *Preferences* and re-open it for the next step)
   - In the **Key Synchronization** section, from the `Publish keys to` drop down list select the new keyserver you just added.
   - Close preferences and try sync

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution from [ubuntuforums](http://www.ubuntuforums.org/). http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1726418

```
gpg --gen-key --enable-dsa2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How would this be helping the user?  This isnt the user's issue, his issue is syncing the keys, not creating a key.

Comment: Agreed. I can create the key without a problem.